# Testing App Based Apple Pay in a Beta Environment

Tags: ios, ios8, stripe-payments, applepay

Is there a way to test the full flow of Apple Pay in a Beta environment?

I have implemented it using the Stripe SDK.
I can get all the way to the point of the Apple Pay details popup screen with the finger print image.
However when I try and use my finger print it tries to process but then throws an error saying, "Apple Pay Is Not Available in 'App Name'"

I have Apple Pay setup on my project under the Capabilities section of the project settings.

I don't know if this is just because it is not in a live enviornment, or if there is something else going on.

Has anyone else seen this, or know if there is a way to test from Beta so I can very every is setup correctly before I submit to Apple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

Turns out we had created the Merchant ID but never created the certificate.
After following the steps [outlined here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/apple-pay), it is working.

Comment: how you are testing apple pay in your device? In your device have you configured a Test Card account or Real card account or it is not required?

Comment: @kdbdallas how can testing for apple pay in sandbox environment can be possible which you have not explained in your answer. Can please update answer how you did actually. Hope you understood what's requirement here.

Comment: Working with stripe, we are able to go through the flow and while in staging we are just not charged. When you are using stripe and and use the simulator they have have "fake-apple-pay" UI that you can implement so you can still test the end points