# iOS ApplePay in sandbox environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, applepay

Is there any way to test Apple Pay in a sandbox environment?

The above question [Testing App Based Apple Pay in a Beta Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725710/testing-app-based-apple-pay-in-a-beta-environment) was not usefull.

Note : I know whole flow for using Apple Pay but question is using in sandbox environment like push notification.

**EDIT** : Is real credit card needed to test Apple Pay?

Answer (score 1):

A real card is needed to populate the Apple Pay settings but check with your back-end processor on how they handle test transactions. For example, when you use testing credentials, Stripe understands and does not actually charge your Apple Pay transaction. I can't speak for other processors, but I would expect those to have similar functionality.