# Apple Pay is not available in "APP"

Tags: applepay

Thanks in advance

I am using Apple Pay in my application, i registered new merchant id in Apple and certificate from payment gateway.

By using this merchant id, payment summery sheet is opening but when i select pay getting error message as below

*Apple Pay is not available in "APP" - check the settings in this app and make sure it was designed to use Apple Pay.*

What could be the problem, and how much time it will take to activate the merchant id with Apple & payment gateway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618296/stripe-and-apple-pay-not-working-in-ios-app

Comment: Do u have any solution for this..?

Comment: hey, I know its been a while, i am facing the same issue. i believe we should add the permission in the info.plist. can you please update me on the matter (where can i find the permission needed) thanks

Answer (score 12):

I guess you created the Merchant ID but never created the certificate, refer to this  https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/apple-pay

Comment: [This link](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devb2e62b839) is more helpful.

Comment: @TheTiger 's answer is more helpful when you try setting Apple Pay-basis or Stripe-service less popular to use

Comment: This is the latest doc link:
https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-apple-pay#create-a-payment-processing-certificate

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a certificate and assign to your app.

Follow the step *Create a payment processing certificate*:

https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devb2e62b839