# Apple pay getting error related app is not available

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, applepay

we are developing app in flutter and integrated apple pay but when we tried to do payment at that getting error like "apple pay is not available".

We set device region as "US".

Sandbox tester and sandbox card also added.

Please check attachment.So anyone have solution regrading this error then tell us.

we tried installed app in device using development, distribution and testflight but in every mode getting same error.

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple Pay is not available in "APP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626788/apple-pay-is-not-available-in-app)

Comment: Before you go too much further, are the benefits of this subscription available in your app or is it a subscription to receive physical goods or services delivered outside the app?  If the subscription provides a benefit/feature in your app then you need to use In App Purchase, not Apple Pay.  If you are going to use Apple Pay then where it says "pay subscription" it needs to say "pay <your company>"

Comment: Also, if you use in app purchase for a feature in your app you cannot provide alternative payment methods, such as PayPal

Answer (score 0):

I used to this issuse.
You must check certificate in developer.apple.com. You go to the certificates,Indentifier & Profile to create => Create certification "Apple pay payment Processing". You should follow the guildline of Apple store to create this certificate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).